# How to change the theme directory uri for localhost?

Tags: theme-development, themes

In wp-config.php I have the following code to change the website path based on the environment of the website.

```
if ( theme_get_environment() === 'local' ) {
    define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://website.local' );
    define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://website.local' );
}
```

The **database** wp_home and wp_siteurl are pointing to the live website. But that is fine because that way I don't need an else statement to also define paths for the website.nl domain.

Now the problem is that when I use `get_theme_file_uri()` it returns this path: `http://website.nl/wp-content/themes/theme2018`. That should be a .local path! So how to fix this?

I already tried to use this approach in `wp-config.php`, but it didn't work:

```
if ( theme_get_environment() === 'local' ) {
    define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://website.local' );
    define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://website.local' );

    // fix theme directory uri for local website
    register_theme_directory('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/wp- 
    content/themes/theme2018');
}
```

So how can I fix the result of `get_theme_file_uri()` to be a local path. Without changing the database values? Defining `WP_HOME` and `WPSITEURL` should be enough, right?

Answer (score 3):

Just found out a solution: The `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` DEFINE statements need to be **above** the `wp-settings.php` include rule inside of `wp-config.php`.